# sugarcrm wrong values display in subpanel

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using sugarcrm 5.4. Under accounts section there is a Quotes subpanel. In the subpanel listing the records showing are right but the grand total column gets the different values. If I print the $bean array the values showing are correct, but while displaying the records it gets the 0.0 for all the records. Here is the screen shot -

[image]

I can't understand what gets wrong.

Any help appreciated!!
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade?  5.4 is very old and likely riddled with bugs.

Comment: The project is very old, and having various customizaions in its core files. So, it is very risky to upgrade the version.

Comment: I wonder if your Grand Total field is the real Total or if it's the total_us field. There are a lot of currency fields inolved. Check the `/custom/modules/Accounts/Ext/Layoutdefs/` to see if you've overridden anything there. Also `custom/modules/Quotes/metadata/subpanels` and corresponding core file locations since those may have changed. What have you customized in the Accounts and Quotes module? Quotes subpanels? Account layoutdefs? Currency or other fields? Start stripping out your customizations and see if that changes anything.

Comment: thaks!!! actually there was some change in the ListView.php file in the process_dynamic_listview_rows() function. $fields array had the incorrect value. now it is solved.